Closed and deleted question about fraud in the 2024 Venezuelan election
My question pertains to the following question:
https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57189/what-evidence-is-there-of-election-fraud-in-the-2024-venezuelan-presidential-ele
It was deemed to fall under "ongoing investigation" and thus closed. That suggests the question should be reopened at a later date when the investigation is done. That sentiment was expressed in multiple comments:

"I can't decide whether to Vote to Close because the journalists and other investigators haven't been given time to investigate this"
"The close votes (as they stand now) aren't because the subject is inherently off-topic, but that it is too soon for us to have sufficient evidence to answer."
"It's impossible to answer to the site's standards for now, so I'm VTC."
"That still falls under the 'ongoing investigation' clause and so this will stay closed."

However, the question was subsequently deleted which makes reopening it impossible.
Given that very few questions are ever deleted on skeptics I would like to know why this one was. It is of course frustrating since I spent a lot of time and effort into writing a question I thought would be a good match for the site.
There are a number of questions on the site about election fraud:

Was there widespread voter fraud in Michigan in the 2020 Presidential Elections?
Is Shiva Ayyadurai's statistical analysis of the 2020 election evidence of widespread fraud?
Were 3 million votes cast by non-citizens in the 2016 US presidential election?
Was there an electoral fraud during the referendum for the independance of Scotland?

Yes/no question about election fraud seem to be on topic in general case, but apparently not when it comes to the election in Venezuela. How come?
Fwiw, the US State Department claims there is "overwhelming evidence" of election fraud.

Looking at the history of the question:
It received 5 close votes from regular users - it was not closed by a moderator, although I mentioned in a comment that I was torn about it.
It also received 2 upvotes and 4 downvotes, giving it a negative score.
It was auto-deleted by a bot.
[I note there was mod action involved, which doesn't make it better for the OP.]
When the question was asked, I posted a number of comments explaining why it was difficult or impossible to answer. In summary:

If the question is "does any evidence exist that the election was fraudulent", it is a shallow and biased question. People claiming that there was fraudulent activity is Bayesian evidence (just not strong evidence).

If the question is "what is the official ruling on whether the election was fraudulent" then the answer will be shallow and pointless: "The election was ratified by [whatever the Venezuelan equivalent of an electoral commission is], and there have been no successful court cases to overthrow it, or you would have heard about it on the international news."

If the question is "What information do you have that hasn't been reported by journalists?" the answer is almost certainly "Nothing." We don't have an arm of investigative journalists or law-enforcement officers fishing out new, never-seen-before evidence. Our role is to popularise what is already known.

If the question is "Do you think it was fraudulent?" it is opinion-based, and off-topic here.


I am sorry you spent so much time on this question and thought it was going to be a good fit here. I hope you can research this for yourself and get a sufficient answer to satisfy your curiosity.
Finally, you write:

very few questions are ever deleted on skeptics

When you get sufficient reputation for access to moderator tools you will be able to see that isn't true.

I didn't know about the existence of the delete bot so thanks for that. I don't think works the same on the other SE sites (at least I haven't seen it) and I think automatically deleting questions (and answers) is absolutely terrible.

Either you have misunderstood Bayesian probability or you are "rules-lawyering" me. Site is called "Skeptics" for a reason and is pretty damn clear from context that "people saying things" is not considered evidence. I feel like you are trying very hard to find ambiguity when there is none.

Roomba is functional on all Stack Exchange sites, and Skeptics is far from its most active area. Forcing content to be manually deleted or stay up is nonsensical when the site mission is considered, and suggesting it would somehow be a net moral, ethical, or mechanical negative to remove the posts that nobody wants to see or read is also nonsense.
